# Removing trailing slash working great, until a query string is present

Tags: .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting

Basically, I have a rewrite rule, that removes the trailing slash from a URL.  I'm currently using IIRF (IIS 6), and the rule will take the following URL and remove the slash like so:

http://test.site.com/home-search/communities/state/city/

and successfully changes it to:

http://test.site.com/home-search/communities/state/city

but when a query string is there, it automatically, adds the trailing slash back in.  So, basically adding ?param1=xx&param2=yy to the URL, re-adds the slash before the query string.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} $ !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,QSA]
```

If I add the following rule, I get a redirect loop that breaks the page, but does remove the trailing slash properly.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1 [R=302,QSA]
```

Any idea what I could possibly be doing wrong?